# Reporting Services Editor cuts off query text

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am designing reporting for SSRS-2005 in Visual Studio 2005 and while editing big queries, the editor stops allowing character input.

Since the editor poor in features, and doesn't allow for commands like CTRL+A, we tend to edit the queries inside of SQL Server Management Console and then paste them into the actual report's dataset query.

That is when the the query get's cut-off. The problem is that once it happens, we simply cannot fix the query. Pasting the query in small blocks doesn't work either. Shut down VS and restart, still won't work.

Stuck and don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I have a suggestion.  Write the large query as a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio.  In SSRS, run the stored procedure to get a data set.

Comment: @dfrevert I can confirm that your suggestion works. Thank you